# java "Could not find or load main class SimpleDotComTestDrive" Error

Tags: java

I have 4 months of programming experience and about 4 days of java (noob alert). This is a battleship example from headfirst Java book. Both files compile, but I keep running into the aforementioned error, and I've tried running the program with -cp command as below:
java -cp Abraxas/java/battleship_1/ SimpleDotComTestDrive
(That is where the class file with main method is saved - right syntax?)
below is my entire code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleDotComTestDrive 
{
public static void main (String[] args) {
    SimpleDotCom dot = new SimpleDotCom();
    int[] locations = {1, 2, 3}; //location of the ship in the array
    dot.setLocationCells(locations);
    String s;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (dot.numOfHits < 3) 
{
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a coordinate ");
        s = in.nextLine();
        dot.checkYourself(s);
        System.out.println("The enemy ship can still take " + dot.hit_pt + " hits!");
}
    System.out.println("you have successfully sunk the enemy ship!");
    System.out.println("You fired " + dot.shots + " shots");
}
}

public class SimpleDotCom 
{
int[] locationCells;
int numOfHits = 0;
int shots = 0;
int hit_pt = 3;

public void setLocationCells(int[] locs) 
{
    locationCells = locs;
}
public String checkYourself(String stringGuess) 
{
    shots++;
    int  guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
    String result = "miss";
    for (int cell : locationCells) 
{
        if (guess == cell) 
{
             result = "hit";
             hit_pt = hit_pt - 1;
             numOfHits++;
             break;
}
}

    if (numOfHits == locationCells.length) 
{
        result = "kill";
}
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
}
```

I would most appreciate if if you guys could help this poor little codito out :3

Comment: does it have package declaration ?

Comment: The name of .java file is ...... ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what package declaration is. Would there be a link to dumbed down explanation for that ?? Also I'd appreciate if you could explain the reason as to why you'd ask that? thanks!

also the name of java files are SimpleDotComeTestDrive.java and SimpleDotCom.java thanks for posting

Comment: The name of the file must match the name of the class.  So `SimpleDotComeTestDrive.java` isn't right for a class called `SimpleDotComTestDrive`.  Lose the second `e`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-cp` argument must identify the directory containing  your `.class` file, not your `.java` file.  For your sanity, I strongly recommend that you, even at this early point in the process, learn to use ant, Maven, Gradle, or some other structured build tool and not just type things at the command line.

Comment: True, but OP said "this is where the class file is saved".  So presumably, this is not what's going wrong.

Comment: I interpreted that as the source file. I am prepared to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I suppose they could have meant "source file".  It's always possible for a beginner to say one thing and mean another.  I do it myself at least three times a day.

Comment: A java source file is a file containing the definition of a class, so a new Java person not draw the distinction. Or they might.